# How to split complex string with different delimiter in Java on Unix server

Tags: java

I have the string like

```
Status:success  //expect in key value pair
Date:02/02/2019 //key=Date and value=02/02/2019
Name:abc
Remarks:category:xyz-info:shjjd jidjhe-DOB:21/07/1988.
```

// key=Remarks and value =category:xyz-info:any info-DOB:21/07/1988, so here we will again split value like

```
Key=category and value=xyz
Key=info and value=any info
```

The above string splitting is working but sometimes Remarks field data is not coming in standard format,it can come like:

1) Remarks:Remarks: Remarks: Category:Abc Info:any info DOB:21/07/1988

2)Remarks: Category:abc-info:any-info which is-having data-DOB:21/07/1988

So like here delimiter is changing, so I could not find the pattern for this. Can someone please help me to resolve this issue. And I want to do this in java for Unix server. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note: I edited the string above to what I *thought* you wanted to say.  Please comment if your intent was different (or edit it yourself of course).

Comment: Three suggestions: 1) keep trying different (probably increasingly complex) regexes until it "works", 2) Instead of relying on Java String.split(), write your own code to do your own parsing, and 3) consider a different tool.  Since you're on Unix, "Perl" or "awk" might be excellent choices.

Comment: Can you specify how do you want to split your 1) and 2) data? Also, your first example is not clear as to what data you expect after recursive splitting.

Comment: What code are you using to split this so called complex string now?

Comment: This doesn't look very complicated, either use a regular expression that will find `word` `:` `rest of string` or if the keys always comes together just see if each line starts with `Status:` or `Date:`and so on.

Comment: But delimeter is changing, it is not always same

Comment: For eg : Remarks : - Remarks : - Category : abc - DOB :21/07/1998 - Info : further info...so this we can split but the prob is delimeter is not fix for eg it can come like Remarks : Category : abc Date of birth : 05-06-1967 info : any info